# Android how to use location.distanceTo()

Tags: java, android, string, google-maps, location

I am using a fragement, I need to get my currently Location (lat and lng)
and I need to calculate my currently location with the destination location.

Can you pls give me a hand. what is the best way to calculate the location:

**How can I get the distance from my currently location and the destination location using lat and lng ;**

```
    LocationManager locationManager;
    Location locatio;



locationManager = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);





String product_latitude     = "3.121191";
            String product_longtitude   = "101.673298";

            Double latitude     = Double.valueOf(product_latitude);
            Double longtitude   = Double.valueOf(product_longtitude);

            // Calculate the Distance
            String product_distance = location.distanceTo(latitude, longtitude);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I get the distance from my currently location and the destination location using lat and lng ?

Answer (score 20):

**Try this**

```
double latitude=lat;
double longitude=lng;    
float distance=0;
Location crntLocation=new Location("crntlocation");
crntLocation.setLatitude(currentLatitude);
crntLocation.setLongitude(currentLongitude);

Location newLocation=new Location("newlocation");
newLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
newLocation.setLongitude(longitude);


//float distance = crntLocation.distanceTo(newLocation);  in meters
distance =crntLocation.distanceTo(newLocation) / 1000; // in km
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use static method of Location: **distanceBetween** to get distance between 2 locations.

```
float [] results = new float[5]; 
Location.distanceBetween(startLatitude, startLongitude, endLatitude,
endLongitude, results)
```

doc: [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[]))

Answer (score 0):

Use Direction API to find to the distance from your current location to the destination. It returns a JSON object as distance which gives you the distance in mile,  you can parse that JSON and display that on your app screen.

For Google's official documentation read [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#DirectionsResponses).

And for a tutorial read [here](http://javapapers.com/android/draw-path-on-google-maps-android-api/).

Hope this would help!!!

Answer (score 0):

"distanceTo" gives an approximate result...

You can use DistanceMatrix API to get a close to accurate results.

[DistanceMatrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#traffic-model)