# Android : Show MapMarker info when user is in 20m way

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps, location

I am new in Android developing, and took a hard one for first project. :D

So the back story :

I have MapActivity what gets MapMarkers from MySql DB (php -> Json)

Now I have a map where are some Marks and user location is known.

**And what I want to do?**
Simple.. when user gets near to marker (lets say 20m) then he will get 
popup where he can submit that he is there..

Problem is that I have no idea how to do it..
My Code is bad, but it works :D.

For rights I have fast workaround (Lenovo tab is with bit old Android, but other way works on Android 7.1..  I hope someone can help me out here. :).

```
public class kaart extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    MapFragment mapFragment;
    GoogleMap gMap;
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    CameraPosition cameraPosition;
    LatLng center, latLng;
    String title;
    String kirjeldus;
    String vahend;

    public static final String ID = "id"; //god to use for marker detection
    public static final String TITLE = "nimi";
    public static final String KIRJELDUS = "kirjeldus";
    public static final String LAT = "lat";
    public static final String LNG = "lng";
    public static final String VAHEND = "vahend";

    private String url = "https://lammerdis.ee/orient/";
    String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.kaart);

        mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.kaart);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        gMap = googleMap;
        gMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
        gMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);  //Võimalikud valikud  MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE, MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN, MAP_TYPE_HYBRID, MAP_TYPE_NORMAL
        gMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        gMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        gMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        gMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

        // Kaardi alguse asukoha Zoomime Aida juurde
        center = new LatLng(59.175597, 25.022103);
        cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(center).zoom(10).build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        getMarkers();

    }

    private void addMarker(LatLng latlng, final String title, final String kirjeldus, final String vahend) {
        markerOptions.position(latlng);
        markerOptions.title(title);
        markerOptions.snippet(kirjeldus);

        if (vahend.equalsIgnoreCase("auto")) {
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.auto));
        } else {
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.jala)); }

        gMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    }

    // Korjame JSON-ist punktid kokku
    private void getMarkers() {
        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.e("Response: ", response.toString());

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    String getObject = jObj.getString("punktid");
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(getObject);

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        title = jsonObject.getString(TITLE);
                        kirjeldus = jsonObject.getString(KIRJELDUS);
                        vahend = jsonObject.getString(VAHEND);
                        latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LAT)), Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LNG)));

                        // Kuvame andmed kaardile
                        addMarker(latLng, title, kirjeldus, vahend);
                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(kaart.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_json_obj);
        //kui punktid kaardil ja seadmes on lubatud asukohta otsida, siis kuvame kasutaja asukoha ka
        //Kui on vanem android siis saame Manifestis kirjeldatud õigustega hakkama ja saaba sukoha kuvatud
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==
                                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); //Kuvab asukoha punktina kaardil
                    gMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true); // Kuvab asukoha nupu (viskab ilusti oma asukohale)
                } else {
                    //Kui on android 6.0 või uuem siis tuleb õiguseid küsida rakenduse käivitamisel
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {
                                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION },
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                    //Kui õigused on lubatud siis tuleb neid rakendada, kõige lihtsam on kasutajale pasundada, et rakenduse restardiks

                    final Toast tag = Toast.makeText(this, R.string.OIGUSE_INFO, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    tag.show();

                    new CountDownTimer(50000, 1000)
                    {
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {tag.show();}
                        public void onFinish() {tag.show();}
                    }.start();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You will need to use a location listener https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

Comment: Ty for response, i got so far also but i have no idea how to write it so that it will detect markers on map also range should be 20m :(

Comment: On your OnLocationResult method you would have a condition checking if is near any of your markers 
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdates/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdates/MainActivity.java
you can check distances using Location.distanceto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28209548/android-how-to-use-location-distanceto

Comment: So probaly i need to use array with cordinates and need to compare all the time if it is near of any marker, when its near then it should take id from array, takes the snipet value and ads it to somekind view. Sad thing is that i need this app just for 8 hours and after that it will be history :D

Comment: Well, there is another way, you could set up geofences

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Comment: Holy ...Exactly what i need.. Tons of hours of google and did not saw this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up GeoFences ( https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html ) with these you can create an area where when the user enters it or it you will get an intent in your intent service then it's just a matter of use that info wherever you like.